# Discord.js limit awaitMessage to 1 channel

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I got a issue with a ticket system I made. Currently if the bot has 2 tickets open with questions and is awaiting for a response it takes the response from other channels. Is there a way to only accept the message in the destination channel? The bot has 3 reactions on a message, if you react it makes a new channel and asks you a few questions. These questions interfere with each other

```
bot.on('messageReactionAdd', (reaction, user) => {

    if (user.bot) {
        return;
    }

    reaction.users.remove(user.id)

    bot.users.fetch(user.id).then((user) => {

        let channelId = "";

        let query = `SELECT * FROM ticketMessage`;
        db.get(query, (err, row) => {

            let ticketMessage = row.MessageId;
            if (reaction.emoji.name == "" && reaction.message.id == ticketMessage) {

                const startTicket = async (name) => {
                    reaction.message.channel.guild.channels.create(user.username + name, {
                            type: 'text'
                        })
                        .then(channel => {
                            let category = "";

                            category = reaction.message.channel.guild.channels.cache.find(c => c.name.toLowerCase() == "tickets" && c.type == "category");

                            if (!category) {

                                user.send("Couldn't Process your ticket since there is no category setup for it!")

                            } else {

                                channel.setParent(category.id)

                                channelId = channel.id

                                sendQuestions()

                            }

                        }).catch(console.error);
                }

                startTicket(" Dino Lines");


                const sendQuestions = async () => {

                    ticketChannel = bot.channels.cache.get(channelId)
                    const filter = m => m.author.id === user.id && m.channel === ticketChannel;

                    ticketChannel.send("What are the names of the dino's you would like to buy, Example => (T-rex, Bronto)?")
                    ticketChannel.awaitMessages(filter, {
                            max: 1,
                            time: 120000
                        })
                        .then(collected => {

                            let dinoName = collected.first().content

                            ticketChannel.send("How many dino's would you like to buy, Example => (Dino1: 5, Dino2: 3)?");
                            ticketChannel.awaitMessages(filter, {
                                    max: 1,
                                    time: 120000
                                })
                                .then(collected => {

                                    let amount = collected.first().content

                                    ticketChannel.send("What kind of currency would you like to use, Example => (Money, Items, Recources)?");
                                    ticketChannel.awaitMessages(filter, {
                                            max: 1,
                                            time: 120000
                                        })
                                        .then(collected => {

                                            let currencyKind = collected.first().content

                                            ticketChannel.send("Do you want to submit this ticket? => (Yes, No)");
                                            ticketChannel.awaitMessages(filter, {
                                                    max: 1,
                                                    time: 120000
                                                })
                                                .then(collected => {

                                                    let yn = collected.first().content

                                                    if (yn.toLowerCase() == "yes") {
                                                        embed1 = new Discord.MessageEmbed
                                                        ticketChannel.bulkDelete(8, true)
                                                        embed1
                                                            .setTitle(user.username + "'s Ticket")
                                                            .addFields({
                                                                name: "Buying Dino Lines",
                                                                value: "\u200b \n **Dino Names:** " + dinoName + "\n **Dino Count:** " + amount + "\n **Payment Methode:** " + currencyKind,
                                                                inline: true
                                                            }, )
                                                            .setFooter(settings["Embeds"].displayname, settings["Embeds"].image)
                                                            .setColor(settings["Embeds"].color)
                                                            .setTimestamp()
                                                        ticketChannel.send(embed1)
                                                    } else {
                                                        ticketChannel.send("Okay ticket canceled!");
                                                    }

                                                })


                                        })

                                })

                        })

                }


            } else if (reaction.emoji.name == "⚔️" && reaction.message.id == ticketMessage) {

                const startTicket = async (name) => {
                    reaction.message.channel.guild.channels.create(user.username + name, {
                            type: 'text'
                        })
                        .then(channel => {
                            let category = "";

                            category = reaction.message.channel.guild.channels.cache.find(c => c.name.toLowerCase() == "tickets" && c.type == "category");

                            if (!category) {

                                user.send("Couldn't Process your ticket since there is no category setup for it!")

                            } else {

                                channel.setParent(category.id)

                                channelId = channel.id

                                sendQuestions()

                            }

                        }).catch(console.error);
                }

                startTicket(" Boss Fights");


                const sendQuestions = async () => {

                    ticketChannel = bot.channels.cache.get(channelId)
                    const filter = m => m.author.id === user.id && m.channel === ticketChannel;

                    ticketChannel.send("What are the names of the bossfights you would like to buy, Example => (Dragon, Broodmother)?")
                    ticketChannel.awaitMessages(filter, {
                            max: 1,
                            time: 120000
                        })
                        .then(collected => {

                            let bossName = collected.first().content

                            ticketChannel.send("How many people are joining?, Example => (Fight1: 5, Fight2: 3)?");
                            ticketChannel.awaitMessages(filter, {
                                    max: 1,
                                    time: 120000
                                })
                                .then(collected => {

                                    let amount = collected.first().content

                                    ticketChannel.send("What kind of currency would you like to use, Example => (Money, Items, Recources)?");
                                    ticketChannel.awaitMessages(filter, {
                                            max: 1,
                                            time: 120000
                                        })
                                        .then(collected => {

                                            let currencyKind = collected.first().content

                                            ticketChannel.send("Do you want to submit this ticket? => (Yes, No)");
                                            ticketChannel.awaitMessages(filter, {
                                                    max: 1,
                                                    time: 120000
                                                })
                                                .then(collected => {

                                                    let yn = collected.first().content

                                                    if (yn.toLowerCase() == "yes") {
                                                        embed1 = new Discord.MessageEmbed
                                                        ticketChannel.bulkDelete(8, true)
                                                        embed1
                                                            .setTitle(user.username + "'s Ticket")
                                                            .addFields({
                                                                name: "Buying Dino Lines",
                                                                value: "\u200b \n **Dino Names:** " + bossName + "\n **Dino Count:** " + amount + "\n **Payment Methode:** " + currencyKind,
                                                                inline: true
                                                            }, )
                                                            .setFooter(settings["Embeds"].displayname, settings["Embeds"].image)
                                                            .setColor(settings["Embeds"].color)
                                                            .setTimestamp()
                                                        ticketChannel.send(embed1)
                                                    } else {
                                                        ticketChannel.send("Okay ticket canceled!");
                                                    }

                                                })


                                        })

                                })

                        })

                }

            } else if (reaction.emoji.name == "️" && reaction.message.id == ticketMessage) {

                const startTicket = async (name) => {
                    reaction.message.channel.guild.channels.create(user.username + name, {
                            type: 'text'
                        })
                        .then(channel => {
                            let category = "";

                            category = reaction.message.channel.guild.channels.cache.find(c => c.name.toLowerCase() == "tickets" && c.type == "category");

                            if (!category) {

                                user.send("Couldn't Process your ticket since there is no category setup for it!")

                            } else {

                                channel.setParent(category.id)

                                channelId = channel.id

                                sendQuestions()

                            }

                        }).catch(console.error);
                }

                startTicket(" Blue Prints");

                const sendQuestions = async () => {

                    ticketChannel = bot.channels.cache.get(channelId)
                    const filter = m => m.author.id === user.id && m.channel === ticketChannel;

                    ticketChannel.send("Which blueprint would you like to buy?, Example => (Bow, Sadle)?")
                    ticketChannel.awaitMessages(filter, {
                            max: 1,
                            time: 120000
                        })
                        .then(collected => {

                            let bluePrint = collected.first().content



                            ticketChannel.send("What kind of currency would you like to use, Example => (Money, Items, Recources)?");
                            ticketChannel.awaitMessages(filter, {
                                    max: 1,
                                    time: 120000
                                })
                                .then(collected => {

                                    let currencyKind = collected.first().content

                                    ticketChannel.send("Do you want to submit this ticket? => (Yes, No)");
                                    ticketChannel.awaitMessages(filter, {
                                            max: 1,
                                            time: 120000
                                        })
                                        .then(collected => {

                                            let yn = collected.first().content

                                            if (yn.toLowerCase() == "yes") {
                                                embed1 = new Discord.MessageEmbed
                                                ticketChannel.bulkDelete(8, true)
                                                embed1
                                                    .setTitle(user.username + "'s Ticket")
                                                    .addFields({
                                                        name: "Buying Dino Lines",
                                                        value: "\u200b \n **Dino Names:** " + bluePrint + "\n **Payment Methode:** " + currencyKind,
                                                        inline: true
                                                    }, )
                                                    .setFooter(settings["Embeds"].displayname, settings["Embeds"].image)
                                                    .setColor(settings["Embeds"].color)
                                                    .setTimestamp()
                                                ticketChannel.send(embed1)
                                            } else {
                                                ticketChannel.send("Okay ticket canceled!");
                                            }

                                        })


                                })

                        })


                }

            } else if (reaction.emoji.name == "❓" && reaction.message.id == ticketMessage) {

                const startTicket = async (name) => {
                    reaction.message.channel.guild.channels.create(user.username + name, {
                            type: 'text'
                        })
                        .then(channel => {
                            let category = "";

                            category = reaction.message.channel.guild.channels.cache.find(c => c.name.toLowerCase() == "tickets" && c.type == "category");

                            if (!category) {

                                user.send("Couldn't Process your ticket since there is no category setup for it!")

                            } else {

                                channel.setParent(category.id)

                                channelId = channel.id

                                sendQuestions()

                            }

                        }).catch(console.error);
                }

                startTicket(" Random Things");

                const sendQuestions = async () => {
                    ticketChannel = bot.channels.cache.get(channelId)
                    ticketChannel.send("How can we help you?")
                }

            } else if (reaction.emoji.name == "✉️" && reaction.message.id == ticketMessage) {

                const startTicket = async (name) => {
                    reaction.message.channel.guild.channels.create(user.username + name, {
                            type: 'text'
                        })
                        .then(channel => {
                            let category = "";

                            category = reaction.message.channel.guild.channels.cache.find(c => c.name.toLowerCase() == "tickets" && c.type == "category");

                            if (!category) {

                                user.send("Couldn't Process your ticket since there is no category setup for it!")

                            } else {

                                channel.setParent(category.id)

                                channelId = channel.id

                                sendQuestions()

                            }

                        }).catch(console.error);
                }

                startTicket(" Support");

                const sendQuestions = async () => {
                    ticketChannel = bot.channels.cache.get(channelId)
                    ticketChannel.send("How can we help you?")
                }

            }
        })
    })

})
```

Comment: Which channel do you want to limit it to? Couldn't you do something along the lines of `if (message.channel.id != channelid) return;` (where `channelid` is a pre-defined id string)?

Comment: I will try that